# disabling video controls in ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi My Question is want to disable or not to show the video controls if i use ACTION_VIEW for any videos. Do i need to specify any extras for Intent or is there any proper way to achieve this

below is the code for reference

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(appnamesArray[arg2]));
```

Any Sample links or code helps me a lot

Thanks in Advance

EDIT:

As i understood that action_view starts the default player or user selected player so the controls goes to player and intent has no control to hide it for that i used videoview to show the video from url

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

            Uri video = Uri.parse(appnamesArray[arg2]);
            videoView.setMediaController(null);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);

            videoView.start();
            setContentView(videoView);
```

please update me if any one can able to succeed this by doing the ACTION_VIEW itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the view `intent` it will have option to open `video` in all the players that support it. So even if some of the players support hiding controls other might not.

Best solution is to have your own [video view](http://androidfromstart.blogspot.in/2010/05/android-play-video-without-controls.html).

Comment: thanks for answer the problem is playing video from url i have to use intent then how to use custom video view in Intent?

Comment: with your tip i got solution